# Accessing variables between classes

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to create a "real estate" program in which each agent has a list of properties. These properties can either be apartments or houses, and each property can be for rental or for purchase. I am having trouble printing a list of each agent's properties. I can access "address" attribute which is in the Agent class, but am having trouble accessing others. I am also having a hard time accessing attributes which are stored in other classes (purchase price/rental price). I have attempted to pass them as global variables but it doesn't seem to be working.

The agent class giving me trouble is at the bottom of my code. I am very new to object oriented programming and any help is appreciated. Thank you

```
# ======== Property class
class Property():

    def __init__(self, square_feet, num_bedrooms, num_bathrooms):
        super().__init__()
        self.square_feet = square_feet
        self.num_bedrooms = num_bedrooms
        self.num_bathrooms = num_bathrooms

    def prompt_init(self):
        pass

    def display(self):
        print(f'This {self.square_feet} square foot property '
              f'has {self.num_bedrooms} bedroom(s) '
              f'and {self.num_bathrooms} bathroom(s)')

# ======= House class
class House(Property):

    def __init__(self, square_feet, num_bedrooms, num_bathrooms,
                 num_stories, garage, fenced_yard):
        super().__init__(square_feet, num_bedrooms, num_bathrooms)
        self.num_stories = num_stories
        self.garage = garage
        self.fenced_yard = fenced_yard

    def display(self):
        super().display()
        print(f'This property is a house\n'
              f'Number of stories: {self.num_stories}\n'
              f'Garage included: {self.garage}\n'
              f'Fenced in yard: {self.fenced_yard}')

    @classmethod
    def prompt_init(self):
        square_feet = input("How many square feet is the property?: ")
        num_bedrooms = input("How many bedrooms?: ")
        num_bathrooms = input("How many bathrooms?: ")
        num_stories = input("How many stories?: ")
        garage = input ("Is there a garage?: ")
        fenced_yard = input("Is there a fenced yard?: ")
        return self(square_feet, num_bedrooms, num_bathrooms,
                    num_stories, garage, fenced_yard)

# ======== Apartment class
class Apartment(Property):

    def __init__(self, square_feet, num_bedrooms, num_bathrooms, balcony, laundry):
        super().__init__(square_feet, num_bedrooms, num_bathrooms)
        self.balcony = balcony
        self.laundry = laundry

    def display(self):
        super().display()
        print(f'This property is an apartment\n'
              f'Balcony included: {self.balcony}\n'
              f'Laundry included: {self.laundry}')

    @classmethod
    def prompt_init(self):
        square_feet = input("How many square feet is the property?: ")
        num_bedrooms = input("How many bedrooms?: ")
        num_bathrooms = input("How many bathrooms?: ")
        balcony = input("Is there a balcony?: ")
        laundry = input("Is there laundry?: ")
        return self(square_feet, num_bedrooms, num_bathrooms,
                    balcony, laundry)

# ======== Purchase class
class Purchase:

    def __init__(self, price, taxes):
        super().__init__()
        self.price = price
        self.taxes = taxes

    def display(self):
        super().display()
        print(f'This property is for sale\n'
              f'Price: {self.price}\n'
              f'Property Taxes: {self.taxes}\n')

    @classmethod
    def prompt_init(self):
        global price
        price = input("What is the listing price?: ")
        taxes = input("What is the annual property tax?: ")
        return self(price, taxes)

# ======== Rental class
class Rental:

    def __init__(self, furnished, utilities, rent2):
        super().__init__()
        self.furnished = furnished
        self.utilities = utilities
        self.rent = rent2

    def display(self):
        super().display()
        print(f'This property is a rental\n'
              f'Monthly rent: {self.rent}\n'
              f'Utilities: {self.utilities}\n'
              f'Furnished or Unfurnished: {self.furnished}')

    @classmethod
    def prompt_init(self):
        global rent
        rent = input("What is the monthly rent?: ")
        utilities = input("What are the monthly utilities?: ")
        furnished = input("Is the rental furnished?: ")
        return self(rent, utilities, furnished)

# ======== Listing Type Classes
class ApartmentRental(Apartment, Rental):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(Apartment, Rental)

    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        prompt1 = Apartment.prompt_init()
        prompt2 = Rental.prompt_init()
        return prompt1, prompt2

class ApartmentPurchase(Apartment, Purchase):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(Apartment, Purchase)

    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        prompt1 = Apartment.prompt_init()
        prompt2 = Purchase.prompt_init()
        return prompt1, prompt2

class HouseRental(House, Rental):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(House, Rental)

    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        prompt1 = House.prompt_init()
        prompt2 = Rental.prompt_init()
        return prompt1, prompt2

class HousePurchase(House, Purchase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(House, Purchase)

    @staticmethod
    def prompt_init():
        prompt1 = House.prompt_init()
        prompt2 = Purchase.prompt_init()
        return prompt1, prompt2

# ======== Agent class
class Agent():

    agentlist = []

    def __init__(self):
        self.properties = []

    listing_type = {tuple(['apartment', 'rental']): ApartmentRental,
                    tuple(['apartment', 'purchase']): ApartmentPurchase,
                    tuple(['house', 'rental']): HouseRental,
                    tuple(['house', 'purchase']): HousePurchase}

    def add_property(self):
        if Agent not in self.agentlist:
            self.agentlist.append(self)
        address = input("What is the property street address?: ")
        property_type = input("Is this property a house or apartment?: ").lower()
        purchase_type = input("Is this property a rental or a purchase?: ").lower()
        listing_class = self.listing_type[(property_type, purchase_type)]
        type = listing_class.prompt_init()
        self.properties.append(address)
        self.properties.append(property_type)
        self.properties.append(purchase_type)
        global rent
        global price
        var1 = rent
        var2 = price
        if purchase_type == "rental":
            self.properties.append(var1)
        elif purchase_type == "purchase":
            self.properties.append(var2)

    def list_properties(self):

# ====== prints list of objects
        for i in range(len(Agent.agentlist)):
            print(self.properties[i])

# ====== doesn't work
#        newlist = []
#        for i in range(len(Agent.agentlist)):
#            newlist.append(self.properties[i])
#            print(newlist)


rent = ''
price = ''

agent1 = Agent()
property1 = Agent.add_property(agent1)

print("Agent1 properties:")
agent1.list_properties()

#agent2 = Agent()
#property2 = Agent.add_property(agent2)
```

Comment: My apologies, as I mentioned I am still learning. I will provide better example code next time

Comment: You don't need to apologize. I was just trying to tell you how to improve the chances that you'll get high quality answers to your question and to make it less work for others to help you. Yes, that does mean it'll require more work you part. Please indicate where exactly in the code you aren't able to access variables between classes, what they are,  and what happens (or doesn't happen) when you attempt to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have an initialized agentlist, then in the **init** you have an initialized properties list. Can you clarify the difference between these two? Is agentlist a list of agents? If so, you will want to keep track of this outside the class, and list only Agent objects that were instantiated (presumably in main). It seems like the problem portion may be in this class method:

```
    def list_properties(self):

# ====== prints list of objects
        for i in range(len(Agent.agentlist)):
            print(self.properties[i])
```

You won't have an easy time running through a list of instantiated Agent objects within the class itself, since your agent list is also defined inside the class declaration.

Then again, I have trouble reproducing or understanding the exact issue. Like a commenter said, it would help to isolate the portion where the problem exists.

Comment: Yes, properties is a list of each agent's properties, and agentlist is a list of every agent. This suggestion makes a lot of sense to me thank you. I will try making agentlist its own class